# Pygame (on Python 3.7) installation in cmd prompt displays 'python' is not recognized

Tags: python, windows, pip, pygame, python-3.7

Edit: I reinstalled python 3.7 but this time I check the box while going through installation process to make it add Python to the Path ( something I tried but it just never worked for some reason). I followed the first link ( the video) step by step and got pygame installed pretty quickly. (:

I am running Python 3.7 and have pip installed with it, along with pygame downloaded. I have searched YouTube videos on how to download and get pygame to work and the most helpful video was: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGb5EX3XjdI&t=116s

Meanwhile I also found out that I may need to change my PATH: https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

I've  made a new path and I always make sure I am in the right drive but I still cannot for the life of me figure out why pygame cannot be installed and why windows command prompt tells me *"'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*

I am new to python programming and wanted to make my first application to be a simple tetris game or something but I am having issues figuring this one out. Thanks for any help if any comes my way.

Comment: Have you changed your `PATH` variable to include the path to the python executable? Make sure you have, and then reboot (not technically necessary anymore, but let's be safe). If you think you did and it still does not work, please show use the value of `PATH`, e.g. run `echo %PATH%` in the console.

Comment: I'm glad everything worked out.  Selecting my answer as the one that helped you helps others if they have the same questions and it gives me more rep (which is good :))  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, I suggest uninstalling and reinstalling python.  Your problem was that you didn't add python to your PATH, so make sure you include that step when you're reinstalling it (it'll be a small check box, see below). As you can see, there is a checkbox that says "Add Python 3.6 to PATH".  This essentially adds Python to CMD automatically.  Best of luck.

[image: Refer to add Python 3.6 to PATH]